# Why does my Excel COUNTIF function always return a value of “0”?

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

My HTML is:

```
div class="medium-insert-images" data-media-id="47deed170ef76561" data-original-width="590" data-original-height="350" contenteditable="false"figure    img src="https://cdn-blog.scorum.com/production/stanleyasokingz/47deed170ef76561_500" alt="" class="" data-original-width="590" data-original-height="350"        figcaption style="word-wrap: break-word; overflow: hidden;" class=""a href="https://www.google.com.ng/search?q=carlo+ancelotti&amp;prmd=inv&amp;source=lnms&amp;tbm=isch&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjN86zU87DmAhXwxoUKHfngCOgQ_AUoAXoECA4QAQ&amp;biw=360&amp;bih=560&amp;dpr=2#imgrc=avYy2TdjA1htFM"source/a/figcaption/figure/divpLooks like clubs firing their managers in an extreme fashion is whats in vogue lately. Within couple of months ago, we can definitely count about 7+ coaches who were relieved of their duties. Some come in as a shock while the others were expectant. Carlo Ancelotti becomes the latest victim to this sack riot as he parted ways with Napoli on Tuesday night after enormous champions league win over Genk and an advancement to the Round of 16. This is the second time I'm seeing a coach get sacked after winning a game. The other was Massimiliano Riccini who allowed his youth boys win 27-0./ppNo doubt the Italian is a high profiled coach with trophies and achievements at his name but this time, things really fell apart for him. Carlo went Nine games without a win in all competition until his Tuesday victory over Genk. Though he finished in second position last season after he took over from Mauzirio Sarri who left for Chelsea, the point gap between league winners (Juventus) and second placed Napoli was huge (11). This season they lie at the seventh position, far beyond the reach of the title. All hope lies in making top four for next season champions league game./pdiv class="medium-insert-images" data-media-id="84ca0d4c9366c665" data-original-width="678" data-original-height="452" contenteditable="false"figure    img src="https://cdn-blog.scorum.com/production/stanleyasokingz/84ca0d4c9366c665_500" alt="" class="" data-original-width="678" data-original-height="452"        figcaption style="word-wrap: break-word; overflow: hidden;" class=""a href="https://www.google.com.ng/search?q=carlo+ancelotti&amp;prmd=inv&amp;source=lnms&amp;tbm=isch&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjN86zU87DmAhXwxoUKHfngCOgQ_AUoAXoECA4QAQ&amp;biw=360&amp;bih=560&amp;dpr=2#imgrc=w6Ko_ZY8PYDB4M"source/a/figcaption/figure/divpLast month the manager and Napoli players were in a high-profile dispute with president Aurelio de Laurentiis. De Laurentiis ordered the team to attend a week-long training camp but Ancelotti and his players all returned home. This should be another reason for the untimely sack. The current relationship between Ancelotti, the president De Laurentiis and the club which is based on friendship, mutual esteem and respect looks like it remains unchanged despite sack. The funny part comes in here. Immediately after the victory over Genk, Ancelotti had told reporters he had no intention of resigning from his post. â€œIâ€™ll see the President [on Wednesday] and weâ€™ll see,â€  he said, not knowing the plans they've got for him. You never can tell, maybe he was even sacked while the game was going on. Just that there was no public hearing./ppbWas Ancelotti devalued?/b/ppThe Italian man is a fine and decorated coach though sometimes bad moments can make you look odd./pdiv class="medium-insert-images" data-media-id="1661b243aab20c0d" data-original-width="634" data-original-height="422" contenteditable="false"figure    img src="https://cdn-blog.scorum.com/production/stanleyasokingz/1661b243aab20c0d_500" alt="" class="" data-original-width="634" data-original-height="422"        figcaption style="word-wrap: break-word; overflow: hidden;" class=""a href="https://www.google.com.ng/search?q=ancelotti+wins+epl+with+chelsea&amp;prmd=niv&amp;source=lnms&amp;tbm=isch&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=2ahUKEwj90-6Z9bDmAhXkxoUKHXulAbgQ_AUoAnoECA8QAg&amp;biw=360&amp;bih=560&amp;dpr=2#imgrc=9n7tobUo445MeM"source/a/figcaption/figure/divpAncelotti, who won the Premier League and FA Cup Double with Chelsea in 2009-10, has been linked with the vacant managers' jobs at Arsenal and Everton and he is one out of the only three managers who boasts of winning three European Cups/Champions Leagues. The list contains Liverpool legend Bob Paisley and Zinedine Zidane. He won two Champions Leagues with AC Milan and one with Real Madrid, as well as domestic titles with Milan, Chelsea, Paris St-Germain and Bayern Munich. Carlo Ancelotti is the only manager in UCL history to guide a club from each of Europeâ€™s top five leagues to the knock-out stages. ChelseağŸ ´ó  §ó  ¢ğŸ‡«ğŸ‡´, PSGğŸ‡«ğŸ‡· , Bayern MunichğŸ‡©ğŸ‡ª , Real MadridğŸ‡ªğŸ‡¸ , AC Milan, NapoliğŸ‡®ğŸ‡¹ . Now heâ€™s done it with two Italian clubsğŸ’¥ğŸ’¥ğŸ‘ ğŸ ½. Accolades well deserved./pdiv class="medium-insert-images" data-media-id="42739a09954383f7" data-original-width="720" data-original-height="418" contenteditable="false"figure    img src="https://cdn-blog.scorum.com/production/stanleyasokingz/42739a09954383f7_500" alt="" class="" data-original-width="720" data-original-height="418"        /figure/divp class=""Gennaro Gattuso has been appointed and given the opportunity as head coach following Ancelotti's sack. 41 years old Gattuso led AC Milan to the fifth position in Seria A last season but parted with the club this summer despite having ta years to run in his sea./ppHe equally spent 13 seasons with the club as a player and several of them under Ancelotti.br/ph2Thanks For Reading.../h2div class="medium-insert-images" data-media-id="3eae9990c5e1b49a" data-original-width="1024" data-original-height="1024" contenteditable="false"figure    img src="https://cdn-blog.scorum.com/production/stanleyasokingz/3eae9990c5e1b49a_800" alt="" class="" data-original-width="1024" data-original-height="1024"        /figure/div
```

My fomula is:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A1,"*img*")
```

The value should be 4, but it returns 0.

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of times "img" appears in that wall of text, in a single cell? That's not what COUNTIF does. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34

Comment: @wysiwyg Just to humor the OP though, can you explain how to achieve the intended effect?

Comment: I counted 8, `img src` 4X and `#imgrc` 4x

Comment: I am more confused by the HTML.  is this a new feature of Excel?  If its just a string, one option is to find the length of A1, then substitute "" in for img, then subtract the new length from the old and divide the difference by length of img.

Comment: Hi @Toria,, it's more than a  sentence in fact  is a paragraph,,, now be specific that what exactly U r trying to do,, I guess that you are trying to count occurrence of TEXT in cell,, or in page ,, in paragraph !!

Comment: @Arctiic I don't know how to achieve that effect, nor was I clear if that was in fact what the OP was intending, which is why I didn't post an answer. However a quick Google search turns up this technique, which sounds like what Forward Ed is suggesting: https://exceljet.net/formula/count-specific-words-in-a-cell

Answer (score 0):

The following formula will test a single cell for the string. (The modified string I use in it is equivalent to the string the OP used. It's just the version needed for the usage here.)

```
=SUM(IF(MID(J14,SEQUENCE(LEN(J14)),3)="img",1,0))
```

And so does the slightly shorter, but "slicker":

```
=SUM(  (  MID(J14:J14,SEQUENCE(LEN(J14)),3)="img"  )  *1)
```

although I prefer the first. Also, note that the comparison clause MUST be in its own parentheses, or it fails. Worth noting that that is a frequent cause of this kind of clause to fail in a most baffling way since it seems like it should work for you. A failed formula of this kind can often be fixed with this alone.

They both test each three character string in the selected text, as well as the two and one character strings made up of the last two and one characters of the string. (That last part might matter and need accounted for if searching for two or single character strings instead of a three character string.)

Note that the formula the OP uses CANNOT produce the correct "8" or even the "4" she believes correct. It is checking the cell, not the elements of the string and so if the `img` exists in it, that makes the cell `*img*`... and it counts "1" and moves on. It does not look at every combination the way the above explicitly does and note that there are more examples.

And it CAN'T. Think of the string:

aaaimgabcd

`img` is an obvious match with the `aaa` at the start being the one asterisk wildcard, then the "abcd" being the second asterisk wildcard. But `a*imgabc*` is a match too, and `*imgab*` and... well... and so on: LOTS of combinations of the wildcard standing in for all characters not `img` or some. And that's with just seven extra characters to make those combinations with. Her string is 5,925 characters long so... `COUNTIF()` has an impossible task to do its designed cell-level work and then try to do cell-interior wok too.

As written, it should give "1" for its result. And does, for me. So I cannot directly troubleshoot it.

The formula given above works on a single cell or a single cell range (like `A1:A1`) but fails if given a multi-cell range. I believe that can be adapted, probably some way to sort of "nest" an outside level but it's not asked for and it's 3:30 am.

Last note. Excel can regard anything as a string except its own formulas. Since it doesn't have a `=HTML()` function (analagous, say, to `=HYPERLINK()`), no HTML can carry in it a method of stopping Excel's string functions. Lordy, if we could just put HTML into a cell and Excel ran code based on it, Katie bar the door, there'd be no stopping us. So no hidden or looked past materials in such strings. For that matter, even formulas can be ripped into now, if expected, via `FORMULATEXT()`.